# "Ember serve" command execution takes too much time on Win7

Tags: ember.js

When "ember serve" is being executed, the command window remains as shown in the image:
[When "ember serve" is being executed, the command window remains as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmMbX.png)

and I can not type in any command. Please give me an answer to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: What command you want to type ?. That's started server, which means local development server is started serving in localhost:4200. you can open this page in browser

Comment: for example, I want to type "ember generate controller name-of-controller", to generate a controller, but nothing can be typed in in this state shown in the image, which lasts for a very long time.

Comment: if you want you can open separate command prompt and do all those stuff. if you want to stop server, then you can type Ctrl +C

Comment: you are right. I can generate sth in a separate command prompt. Thanks!

Comment: Actually that's how we will develop ember project, you dont need to stop the server, it will automatically observer file changes and refresh browser for modification...live reload feature super useful for development

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can do the trick is the cmd you are using to be run as administrator.
Second thing that I could think of is using ember-cli-windows which excludes some of the 'unimportant' files when building.
The link for this is right here: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows

Try these two steps and your build time is going to decrease!

Whereas to type new commands you need to close execution first (CTRL-C), then type command you want, then go back and run again (ember s).

Comment: You don't need to stop the server for every file creation. it's not required. you can create it in another cmd window. Restart is required only when you install addon.

Comment: Yeah you can do that too!